# Is there a place to download the Windows 8 System Builder ISO?

Tags: windows, windows-8, bootable-media

I'm looking to install Windows 8 on a new desktop I've built which lacks an optical drive.

Microsoft seems to offer a downloadable upgrade at their [store](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbpage.Windows_8_Pro), but (supposedly?) that can't be used to install Windows on computers without an earlier version of Windows already installed.

Web searching finds sites that claim that Microsoft's [tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) to make Windows 7 USB keys works on Windows 8 ISOs.

So the question is.. where can I download the ISO?

(I'm hoping to finish installation today, rather than waiting a few days for a DVD to come in the mail - and then finding a friend who will let me use their optical drive possessing computer to rip the ISO).

Comment: Haven't come across any Digital River links yet, so I guess the only answer would be MSDN.

Comment: Or possibly if you're in a school that is part of the MSDNAA - which provides keys & ISOs.