# Where can I download a copy of Windows 8 (64 Bit) to use with my previously purchased activation key?

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, ssd, windows-activation

I just bought an HP ultrabook running Windows 8 with no installation media. I also bought an SSD hard drive.

My plan was to install windows 8 on the SSD I purchased. Without any installation media provided with my laptop purchase however, I can't install windows 8 onto my SSD. (I don't even have a cd drive if they gave me a CD).

I managed to retrieve my product key using [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html). And have confirmed it to be correct by verifying the last set of characters found in **Control Panel > System > Activation**

Where can I download a copy of Windows 8 64 bit edition? That is the version of windows installed on my laptop. I can only find references to purchase another copy of windows for $100+ on the internet... which I shouldn't have to do, since I already own a valid Windows 8 license.

Comment: Looks like there's isn't any other place for now [Is there a place to download the Windows 8 System Builder ISO?](http://superuser.com/q/519086) [Where to find the Windows 8 ISO?](http://superuser.com/q/496374)

Comment: @darkAsPitch: What edition is it exactly? Type "winver" in your Run dialogue box and hit enter.

Comment: @Dan, the "Winver" is 6.2, build 9200. Sathya thank you for reinforcing my fears!

Comment: Double-check that there isn't an "emergency" partition on the disk that contains the Windoze install image.  If so, you can run a process to create install CDs from the partition.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Microsoft or HP directly?

Comment: I tried calling HP directly... what a joke. I was transferred around literally 7 times between the same two people. I never even got a word in edgewise. The pick up, say "sorry I'll transfer you to the right department", and before you can even reply you're on hold/being-transferred again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a grey area because you bought a branded PC with windows installed under an OEM license. An OEM license dictates that the software installed should not leave the original hardware. I say grey area because I don't consider changing a harddrive "leaving the hardware" but it technically is. So without possessing the install media (yes I know that's what your looking for >_< but short of a torrent it's not that simple, especially if you want it for free) the only option you are left with is cloning the partition (ghosting the harddrive).

As a work around you could use a live cd such as [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to clone the OS onto your other drive (you might have to resize it first).  I know this isn't optimal. It also might give you guff about not being a genuine copy.

Also note that you can't just get any Windows 8 install disc as it is not a retail key, you need one that works with the specific OEM key you posses.

Comment: Clonezilla Still might be a problem because SSDs tend to be smaller than traditional hard drives around the same price. Some partition resizing might be in order....

Comment: Yep. You take all your user data off that partition and resize it with something like gpart.  Hopefully you can get it small enough to fit your ssd.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing: http://superuser.com/questions/568124/how-to-re-sign-the-windows-boot-loader-to-re-enable-secure-boot-on-an-hp-laptop

Comment: From Vista upwards there is no difference between OEM and retail disks.

Answer (score 0):

Just clone the hard drive over to the ssd, then install ssd and your computer will work as the same. They sell a kit at Microcenter or even Amazon.
I have done it two or three times, no problem

Comment: This was suggested in the other answer.  Please strive to make answers add substantive new aspects not found in any existing answers.